# typescript does not exist on type 'typeof object

Tags: node.js, typescript

I just recently started with typescript,

I was moving my javascript code to typescript. In my JS code, I had something like this

```
export const envVar = {
    SOCIAL_URL: false,
    BASE_CONFIG_URL: '', //we change it based on the request
    BASE_CONFIG_CLIENT_WEB_URL: base_config.client_url || 'http://localhost:3000',
    DB_HOST: db_settings.db_host || 'localhost',
    DB_USER: db_settings.db_user || 'root',
    APP_URL: base_config.app_url || 'blle://',
    DB_PASSWORD: db_settings.db_password || '',
    DB_DATABASE: db_settings.db_database || 'blale',
    DB_CONNECTION_NAME: db_settings.connection_name || '',
    FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL: db_settings.firebase_datbase_url,
    FACEBOOK_APP_ID: facebook.app_id || '',
    FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET: facebook.app_secret || '',
    FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL_SOCIAL: facebook.redirect_url_social || '',
    FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL_AUTH: facebook.redirect_url_auth || '',
    FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL: function() {
        return this.SOCIAL_URL ? this.FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL_SOCIAL : this.FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL_AUTH
    },
    TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY: twitter.api_key || '',
    TWITTER_REDIRECT_URL_AUTH: twitter.redirect_url_auth || '',
    TWITTER_REDIRECT_URL_SOCIAL: twitter.redirect_url_social || '',
    TWITTER_APP_SECRET: twitter.app_secret_key || '',
    TWITTER_REDIRECT_URL: function() {
        return this.SOCIAL_URL ? this.TWITTER_REDIRECT_URL_SOCIAL : this.TWITTER_REDIRECT_URL_AUTH
    },
    JWT_SESSION_DURATION: jwt_config.session_duration || '7d',
    JWT_ISSUER: jwt_config.issuer || 'blle',
    JWT_SECRET: jwt_config.secret || '933dnz82'
}
```

moved this from `module.exports` to `export const`. Now, how can I use it another .ts file? I initially did something like this

```
import * as envVar  from "./../config"

const { JWT_SECRET, JWT_ISSUER, JWT_SESSION_DURATION } = envVar
```

but this is giving following error

> Property 'JWT_SESSION_DURATION' does not exist on type 'typeof

Comment: I don't see `JWT_SESSION_DURATION` in the list of your constants.

Comment: @AnirudhBagri 3rd last from in the envVar object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are doing a named export, your import will receive an object containing `envVar` as one of the property.

So you can do the following.

```
import { envVar }  from "./../config"
```

OR

```
import * as envVar  from "./../config"

const { JWT_SECRET, JWT_ISSUER, JWT_SESSION_DURATION } = envVar.envVar
```

If you want to use the existing import, then you have to change your named export to default export.

```
const envVar = {....};
export default envVar;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// GlobalConfig .ts
export namespace GlobalConfig {
    export var JWT_SESSION_DURATION = { myValue: "4" }
    export const JWT_SECRET = "asasasasas"
}
```

---

And then you can use this in another file like this. Note this is one of the many ways you can do this.

```
//MyCode.ts
import { GlobalConfig } from "./GlobalConfig";

export class SomeComponent {
    current_jwt = "";

    constructor() {
        // some init code
        this.current_jwt = GlobalConfig.JWT_SESSION_DURATION.myValue;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // something
        console.log(this.current_jwt);
        console.log(GlobalConfig.JWT_SECRET);
    }

}
```

Comment: why do we use `namespace` in typescript?

Comment: a namespace is like a package in Java or put simply a substitute for a fully qualified class. Thus while importing the global variables you don't have to create an instance of anything. You can also separate out variables based on use, type etc to ensure security and cross-reaching concerns by creating mulitple namespaces per domain.